# Sum the values of specific categories

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet-function

My Excel looks like this:

```
       A                            B
1   Category                       Hours
2   Administration                  4
3   Programming                     2
4   Administration                  2
5   Programming                     3
6  
7   Total hours of programming:
8   Total hours of Administration:
```

but much much longer.

Now counting the total hours is easy: `=SUM(B2:B5)`.

But, how do I count the total hours of a specific category?
What is the magical function I need?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you threw me off with "count", you want [SUMIF](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-US/article/SUMIF-function-468f6551-8cf3-49dc-a07c-a8f9f05d3dc2)

For counting the number of times an entry occurs use the [COUNTIF](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4) function: